# Send Server-Side Validated Input to New php Page

Tags: php, validation

I am writing the front-end for a project my team is developing. The responsibilities are as follows:

1. page1.php - Receive and validate (on the server) input from the user. Pass 
   validated input to page2.php
2. page2.php - Receive validated input from page1.php and continue processing.

I am responsible for creating page1.php, and my co-worker is creating page2.php.
I am using server-side validation to ensure only valid data is passed on to page2.php. I am using the form attributes referenced below.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Once the data on page1.php has been validated, how do I send it to page2.php? I have considered the following:

1. Header function - does not work because HTML (the form) is sent to obtain the user's input.
2. Session variables - This could work to share the validated input across pages, but it will not load page2.php.

Or is there a better way to construct this? I cannot use JavaScript for validation because I need to validate the data on the server.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You certainly can use javascript for this. Make an ajax call to the server side validation script. That actually is the most elegant way, since you do not have to make a full reload at all. So your call posts for form values for validation, as a result the server returns the second form which you can then insert in the current loaded page.

Comment: explain why the session variable doesn't work for you ??

Comment: Why not store validated input in session variables and then simply do `header'(Location: page2.php');` ?

Comment: @arkascha — That allows the validation to be trivially bypassed. Having the client ask the server if the data is OK is fine. Then having the server then trust the client to say that that data is OK is completely insecure.

Comment: The page will display the form, receive input and validate it. Once it is validated, I wanted to send the validated input to another page for processing. I was saying that this is not possible via header('Location: page2.php'); because HTML will have been sent to the browser by then. Quentin, I am thinking through your suggestion below.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, can't follow you there. Where is the difference to a POST of the values and then delivering a prefilled second form? Certainly you are right that one cannot trust data provided from the server side. But that is a general aspect in web programming. It is irrelevant if the data transmission is done via java or a form post.

Comment: @arkascha — None, which is why delivering a pre-filled second form isn't an acceptable solution either.

Comment: @Quentin So 1. your initial comment was incorrect and now 2. you state that one must not use prefilled forms. Which is also nonsense. Sorry. Same thing is true: you cannot trust those values. So you have to revalidate them. So? If you implement a web application that asks data from the client, which is pretty much most applications, then obviously you have to validate. Do you want to say one must not implement web applications?

Comment: @arkascha — 1. No, it wasn't. You can't make a request to a server to see if some data is safe, and then make another request to a server with some data (which may or may not be the same data because it is a new request) and trust that the data in the second request is safe. It doesn't matter if you use Ajax or a full page reload between the two steps. 2. No, I said that delivering a pre-filled form for step 2 and then trusting that the data in it will be submitted back unaltered is safe. That isn't nonsense. That's web security 101: You can't know that data from the client is data you sent it

Comment: @arkascha — "So you have to revalidate them" — Yes! Except that there is no point in having the first request if you are going to revalidate them because the **only** purpose the first request has was to validate them.

Comment: @Quentin to 1. neither the OP nor me claimed that. In contrary, I explicitly stated that you have to revalidate data from the second form. And there certainly _are_ situations where you want to validate user data in several steps. That is called UX. For example you can have parts of the second form depend on the data provided in the first form.

Comment: @arkascha — You didn't say that. You said that an Ajax call should be made to a validation script which should return a form.

Comment: Sorry, let's stop this. You are trying to justifiy a clearly wrong statement you made. Sorry.

Comment: @arkascha — "For example you can have parts of the second form depend on the data provided in the first form." — You *could*, but again, the sole purpose of the validation script was to validate the data. There's nothing extra added after that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to have the validation logic on a different "page" to whatever the result is.

You shouldn't pass the "this data is OK" message between *pages*, just between functions.

The process should be something like this:

1. Browser requests page with a form on it from the server
2. Server sends the form
3. Browser sends the submitted form data
4. Server checks the form data and determines if it is OK (in which case it processes it and returns the OK page) or if it isn't (in which case it returns an error message and possibly a the form).

A simple example of this would be:

```
include("form-validation.php");
if (submitted_data_ok()) {
    include("put-data-in-database.php");
    include("show-ok-message-to-user.php");
} else {
    include("form.php");
}
```

For a more advanced approach, investigate MVC frameworks.